# Multiple packages call in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script, which executes the command sequentially.
I want to execute in parallel and output should come in the same window.

```
SET product=abc
call %ANT_HOME%\bin\ant -buildfile 
%BUILD_DIR%\Build\Build_Scripts\IIB_Build_Scripts\antBuild.xml -
Dcvs.projectComponents.path="HEAD" -Dproduct.code=abc -Dversion=%version% 
-DActionTask=build build -Dmqsi.workspace.home=%BUILD_DIR%
)
SET product=def

call %ANT_HOME%\bin\ant -buildfile 
%BUILD_DIR%\Build\Build_Scripts\IIB_Build_Scripts\antBuild.xml -
Dcvs.projectComponents.path="HEAD" -Dproduct.code=def -Dversion=%version% 
-DActionTask=build build -Dmqsi.workspace.home=%BUILD_DIR%
)
```

I have gone through the answer, and START is suggested.
The problem is 2 different cmd prompts are appearing.

Thanks

Comment: `start /b` will spawn your `ant` threads within the same window.  See `start /?` for full details.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried and it did fix it..
But cons it opened up so much of windows and cpu usage exceeded 100%

Comment: Try `start /b /belownormal etc...`  Your CPU usage will still be 100%, but the `ant` threads will behave more politely, scaling back usage as other apps demand CPU time.  You should also limit the number of threads to the number of CPU cores in your machine, assuming your `ant` build processes are single-threaded.  If they're already multi-threaded, then spawning multiple parallel builds probably isn't gaining you anything anyway.

Comment: Thanks. let me try and revert on the same.